# Bio7 import modules

Tags: python, dataflow, bio7

I try to using Bio7 dataflow. It's is possible get data frame from R and using in Python scripts. I try to use the following code

```
import pandas as df
print("here we are")
df=RServeUtil.fromR("iris")
print(df)
```

but I have some error in `import` statment.

Comment: please could you add the error messages ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably mix some things:

- Bio7 has nothing with Python, it is IDE for ecological modeling and an API for Java.
- Importing pandas has no meaning in your code.

You got error messages because you probably has not installed pandas.

BTW, more common is to import pandas with the `pd` name:

```
import pandas as pd
```

The name `df` in your code is a common name for a *dataframe*, e. g. pandas' DataFrame - it seems that you were trying to combine you code from 2 different sources, one for pandas and the other for Bio7.

Answer (score 0):

Bio7 uses as default Jython which does not support the general Python packages, see:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jython

http://www.jython.org/

Jython is running in a Java Virtual Maschine process and has access to the Bio7 Java API's which you use in Python syntax but lacks the support of many powerful Python packages.

In additon it is possible to execute Python scripts in Bio7 with a native Python interpreter (The console supports the access, too)

Of course since Bio7 is based on Eclipse you can install a more powerful generel Python and Jython editor (PyDev) with the Bio7 Update Manager, see:

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/pydev-python-ide-eclipse

Bio7 also supports the transfer to Python with a server bridge (P4J: http://py4j.sourceforge.net/) but I think in your case
you could also use a direct R Python bridge, e.g., with:

https://rpy2.bitbucket.io/

if you work rather in Python.

However it depends what you are trying to do. Maybe the use of Jython alone would fit you needs.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested an interesting workaround to call Rserve from Python (not Jython which is supported for Rserve by default).

You can install pyRserve (https://pythonhosted.org/pyRserve/intro.html#documentation) as a Python package.

In Bio7 you can start Rserve with the Rserve action. However you can also change to the native R console by invoking that action again (can also be started alone without Rserve with the available console action).

Please note that all R workspace variables up to that point will be preserved in the native R console, too, because of the special Rserve version in Bio7 on all platforms!

Now I can start Rserve from the R console (not managed from Bio7) with:

```
run.Rserve()
```

Finally I can connect Python to Rserve and evaluate a script like this:

```
import pyRserve 
conn = pyRserve.connect()
conn.eval("print(runif(100))")
#conn.close()
conn.shutdown()
```

In the above example I shutdown Rserve in the script so that I can connect to Rserve again with the Bio7 toolbar action.

With this simple way I can access all currently available R workspace data (e.g, ImageJ data, etc.) in Python or send data from Python
to R.

When you work with an installed PyDev editor plugin in Bio7: https://youtu.be/-kySAN9doXQ

use the 'Run as' action in the dedicated context menu for the Python script.

Please also note when using the PyDev editor to change to the Bio7 console if necessary to see the Bio7 results (see console action 'Display Selected Console')!

Variables from R can be assigned in Python like this example:

```
t=conn.eval("runif(100)")
print t
```